# Using vimscript, how to know if a line's no has changed?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

#### Question

When buffer contents have changed how do I know if a line, having say a line no of 100, has shifted to line no 104?

*Note: Content of the line may change so can't track the line using search patterns.*

#### Hacky Solution

I was thinking using the `TextChanged*` events along with the current cursor position and change in the total number of lines will help. But this seems like it could lead to an incorrect answer.

#### Context

I'm trying to create a [plugin](https://github.com/18alantom/zettel.vim) as a wrapper around vim's tags functionality.

The issue is: if a tag was inserted at line 100 and 4 lines were added above it, the tag points to an incorrect location, i.e. line 100, whereas it should be 104.

How do I calculate this difference of 4?

---

Solutions that apply to both vim and neovim would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless told otherwise, Ctags puts a *search pattern* in your `tags` file, which is used by Vim to move the cursor to the corresponding line and consequently makes the line number irrelevant for the tag-related commands that use your `tags` file… so I wonder if that is not a solution to a non-existing problem.

Comment: The issue with using a search pattern is that changes will have to be tracked within the line to update the search pattern. The line can be updated after the tag has been inserted.

The `textprop` API seems like what I need (if I were to ignore compatibility with neovim).

Comment: Your question mentions moving lines, though, not changing them. You might want to include all your requirements to get actionable answers. Anyway, `:help text-properties` seems appropriate (see `:help prop_find()` but integration with FZF might be complicated since you are not really using tags anymore.

Comment: Yup, updated it. thanks for the `text-properties` suggestion. Any feature that may be neovim and vim cross-compatible to fix this? Or will this issue have to be fixed individually?

Comment: Neovim has incompatible API. I guess you should start looking at `:h api-extended-marks`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).